# how to indicate every subpage of a url in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following if statement:

```
if (url === "/t") { 
          document.querySelector("html").classList.add("custom-homepage"); 
          component.set("displayCustomHomepage", true); 
        } else {  
          document.querySelector("html").classList.remove("custom-homepage"); 
          component.set("displayCustomHomepage", false); 
        }
```

As of now of course this works only to test whether the URL is `example.com/t`. However, what I want is the if condition to be true if the URL is `/t`*or any subpage* also, such as `example.com/t/subpage`. How can I make this work?

Comment: You can try splitting the (full) URL with the slash character specified as the delimiter, then grab the 2nd item from the result of the splitting (which is an array) and check if it equals `t`. Alternatively, you can use the [`startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) method. (P.s. could you please provide more information as to how the `url` variable is set?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are in the browser, you can get pathname from [location object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) and then match `window.location.pathname` against the regex. You can use [startsWith](https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/jsref_startswith.asp), but it will also catch `"/tea"`, and not only `/t`.

```js
const url = new URL('/t/hello', 'http://www.example.com');
const pathname = url.pathname;
console.log(pathname); /* "/t/hello" */
console.log(/\/t(\/.*)?$/.test(pathname)); /* true */

if (/\/t(\/.*)?$/.test(pathname)) {
  // do your stuff
  console.log("hello world");
}
```

If you don't have access to `location`, you can turn your string into [URL object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) and retrieve pathname from there.

Here is how you can decipher [Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). It is enclosed between `/` characters. `\/` matches `/` character, `t` is literally `t`. Inside parenthesis is a capturing group. It can be used to "pull" what matches with it from result, but in this case it is needed to limit, how many times it should be matched - `?` means "zero or one time" and it is applied  to whole group. `.` means "every symbol". `*` is "repeat zero or more times", and `.*` means "any symbol zero or more times". And `$` means "end of string". Here is huge helper, whenever you need to write or parse regular expression: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rACKpN/1/)

**Related:**

- [JavaScript test() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp)

Comment: Nice, it seems to work! Could you kindly explain what all '/\/t(\/.*)?$/' means, though?

Comment: /: start of the regular expression pattern.
\/: match a forward slash character (/). The backslash (\) is used to escape the forward slash because forward slashes are used as the delimiter in the regex pattern.
t: match the letter "t".
(\/.*)?: match zero or one occurrence of a forward slash (\/) followed by any number of characters (.*). 
The . means any character and the * means zero or more occurrences of the previous character.
$: end of the regex pattern